# Amazon S3 only returning Vary headers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I'm trying to setup CORS for my S3 bucket. Below is my configuration -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

When I make a GET request from Postman (including Origin header), I get the below response. The response does not have Access-control-Allow-Origin header but only the Vary header.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 12 Sep 2017 04:24:54 GMT
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
Last-Modified: Tue, 12 Sep 2017 04:09:59 GMT
ETag: "3a0b53f2dee09a17e509c5ba4fb0552"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/css
Content-Length: 3805
Server: AmazonS3
```

How do I get Access-control-Allow-Origin in response?

Comment: did you setup CORS in API gateway?

Comment: The `Origin:` header needs to be in the format `Origin: http://example.com` (or https) including the scheme and host but not a path.  Is this how you are sending it?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes, i have origin in that format. I tried it from curl as well instead of Postman but still the same result. My curl command is `curl -H "Origin: http://example.com" http://MyS3Url`

Comment: Works for me, using your rules on my bucket, with this request, exactly as shown (nothing changed): `curl -v http://sqlbot-cors-test.s3.amazonaws.com -H 'Origin: http://example.com'` returns the expected headers.

Answer (score 0):

Please enable CORS in you API Gateway like below picture. It will provide CORS when you are accesing API from a different domain (S3 bucket in your case)

[image]

Comment: How is this question related to API Gateway?